# how to to send a php http request and retrieve a pdf?

Tags: php, pdf

I'm beginner with PHP, I would like to download a pdf file from an Indy server.

I'm using a http_get to send the request but It seems wrong since all content type that can be returned is text/html.

So my question is quiet simple: which request should I use to retrieve my pdf file??

After retrieving it, I wish to transfert it.But its maybe an other problem.

Comment: In the most basic case, `file_get_contents` with a URL as an argument will do what you want.

Comment: *Any* content type can be transferred via an HTTP GET, not only text/html. Your premise is wrong and hence your question makes little sense.

Comment: you can look at the function `file_get_contents` as @Jon pointed out. You can also look at cURL.

Comment: thanks a lot for fast replying.

Comment: $file = file_gets_content($url); ?
but before isnt something like $file = new_pdf(); ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the cUrl library or simply use `file_get_contents`.
`file_get_contents` return FALSE if the file is not there or whatever and it returns the file contents on SUCCESS. You need to capture the contents of the file and save them locally or output them to the browser.

```
$content = file_get_contents('file.pdf', fopen('https://url.to/file.pdf', 'r'));
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=filename.pdf');
echo $content;
```

Comment: thanks I wish to avoid using cURL, but file_get_contents is doing perfectly what I want, and your answer make it clear.
I will test right now.

Comment: @idan FYI: this does exactly the same thing as `http_get`...

Comment: Hello, the problem is that with file_get_content or http_get my pdf file is convert to text.

Comment: but what I wish is retrieving a pdf file and save it.

Comment: ahhh I ve found what I was looking for in an other post: 


file_put_contents("file.pdf", fopen($url, 'r'));